# Switch off default parallelization

Tags: parallel-processing, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to execute Matheamtica script which should use exactly one core. In the very first line I have put LaunchKernels[1]; Nevertheless when script is running all computer's cores are allocated (96 in total). Of course I would like to run 96 copies of the script using bash scripts.

Is there a way to set a maximum number Mathematica Kernels that may be used by the Mathematica off?

I launch the script as follows (In fact I use a loop and 16 is stored in a variable, but I guess this is not important):

```
/usr/local/bin/MathKernel -script appr.m test_16.00/full.dat test_16.00/one.dat
```

the last two strings are just input and output file name.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is happening without knowing anything about your script.  If you don't use parallel constructs (Parallelize, ParallelTable, etc.), no parallelization is used.  If you use LaunchKernels[1] and you do have parallel constructs, only one subkernel will run and the performance will be *worse* compared to no parallelization at all.  Multiple cores may still be used if you have functions that are internally parallelized and don't require multiple subkernels.  Most such functions use the MKL, e.g. `LinearSolve`.  You can consider asking on mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Comment: no it won't: running 96 single core jobs in parallel almost always will be faster than running single 96 core job. Intrivial cases the speed is equal. Thanks for the MKL hint though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the maximum number of *Mathematica* kernels that will be used with the dialog:
**Edit** > **Preferences** > **Parallel** in the **Parallel Kernel Configuration** section.

You can then limit the number of threads that will be used by the Intel Math Kernel Library, which *Mathematica* uses for a number of machine-precision operations, with the System Option setting:

```
SetSystemOptions["MKLThreads" -> 1]
```

Related question on the proper Mathematica Stack Exchange site:
[How to force an evaluation to use only one core?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31400/121)